# Node JS version keeps defaulting to wrong version

Tags: node.js

I installed Node Version 21.1.0 directly from Node JS. I then do

```
node -v
```

and it spits out

```
v18.16.1
```

I then do

```
nvm uninstall v18.16.1
```

but I get

```
N/A version is not installed
```

Then I do

```
nvm alias default node
```

So that it defaults to the latest v21.1.0

```
nvm use default
```

But running

```
node -v
```

still gives me v18.16.1 which is giving me issues in my Rails project.  My machine is a M1 Mac.

Comment: Probably you have node installed outside of NVM. Try uninstalling node completely until you get command not found for `node`, then installing nvm again.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x?rq=2) shows up in related questions and may help.

Comment: I uninstalled node from every folder path, brew, and node uninstall x version.  I'm wondering how else I installed it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I had installed Node with asdf too

```
 asdf uninstall node
```

did the trick

Comment: For anyone else facing the same issue, running `which node` or `whereis node` may give a clue about where the active node is installed and what needs to be uninstalled.